# Consume IAsyncEnumerable in client-side Blazor / streaming

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, webassembly

Is it possible to consume an endpoint that returns `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` via API from a client side (WASM) Blazor application as a **stream** of data? I'm trying to so using `HttpClient.GetFromJsonAsAsyncEnumerable<T>()`. However this always results in data fully consumed first and then rendered at once, rather than incremental rendering.

```cs
        // service's proxy method on the client side
        public IAsyncEnumerable<int> GetIntStreamAsync()
        {
            return _httpClient.GetFromJsonAsAsyncEnumerable<int>("/api/mysvc/stream");
        }
```

```cs
        // implementation on the server side
        public async IAsyncEnumerable<int> GetIntStreamAsync()
        {
            var val = 0;
            while (val < 10)
            {
                yield return val;
                await Task.Delay(200);
                val++;
            }
        }
```

```cs
// registration of service endpoint on the server side
app.MapGet("/api/mysvc/stream", (IMyService service) =>
{
    return TypedResults.Ok(service.GetIntStreamAsync());
});
```

Razor logic on the client

```
@rendermode InteractiveAuto
@inject BlazorApp1.Client.Services.IMySvc mysvc

@if (_data != null)
{
    <ul>
    @foreach (var item in _data)
    {
        <li>@item</li>
    }
    </ul>
}

@code {
    private List<int> _data = [];

    // onclick handler of a button
    private async Task GetFromServerStreamedAsync()
    {
        _data = [];
        this.StateHasChanged();
        var values = mysvc.GetIntStreamAsync();
        await foreach (var val in values)
        {
            _data.Add(val);
            this.StateHasChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

```
// client-side Program.cs
// register HttpClient to be used in proxies
builder.Services.AddTransient(sp => new HttpClient
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress),
});
```

Interesting is that if I define the same service method locally on the client side, the rendering works as expected. I'm wondering if either the call `_httpClient.GetFromJsonAsAsyncEnumerable` is fetching all data before returning, or perhaps something needs to be enabled on the server (SSR) project to stream the data.